# internal links to dropdown search

Tags: php, html

How do I add links to internal pages (from my own site) to this dropdown. So when someone enters a city it redirects them to the page for that city?

```
<form>  
    <div class="ui container">              
        <select name="city" id="city" class="ui search selection dropdown">     
            <option disabled selected>Pick a City</option>          
            <option value="vancouver.php">Vancouver</option>            
            <option value="Victoria">Victoria</option>          
            <option value="Whistler">Whistler</option>      
        </select>               
       <button id="search" class="ui button">Search</button>                        
    </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You want to redirect when search button clicked or directly when anybody changes the option redirect him to URL.